# Need to get information about video when user tap on Iframe embedded on WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, webview, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

As in image, I have blog that contain video and what I want is when ever user tapped on it I need total video information like duration, title, etc.[image: Please check attached image which is WKWebView Image]

Answer (score 0):

Because the interaction you are trying to observe is occurring in the context of the web browser and not the context of `UIKit`, your best bet is to inject JavaScript into the page to interact with DOM content.  (I am not qualified to tell you how the JavaScript might work).

To get results back, `WKWebView` has:

```
func evaluateJavaScript(_, in:, in:, completionHandler:)
```

and

```
func callAsyncJavaScript(_, arguments:, in:, in:, completionHandler:)
```

Comment: Can you share javascript code which need to be inject while loading web view?

Comment: I don't know enough about JavaScript and the DOM to be able to help.

Comment: Okay no problem. let me know if you get anything